# How can I make text appear in circle

Tags: python, tkinter, text, tkinter-canvas

[image]

How can I make text appear in circle like in the picture?

Comment: I'm not certain that it's even possible with just Tkinter. AFAIK, Tkinter's text-rendering capabilities don't provide any way to rotate text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to rotate text around (or inside) a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652414/is-there-a-way-to-rotate-text-around-or-inside-a-circle)

Comment: @stovfl I've just quoted that question in my answer.

Comment: @scotty3785 Yes, but this does not prevent me to vote as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56653517/2323393 suggests that you can use the `angle` attribute of the text object to rotate it.

For example

```
txt = canvas.create_text(250, 250, text='Hi')
canvas.itemconfig(txt, angle=90)
```

Or a more complete solution

```
import math
import tkinter as tk

def draw(angle, text):
    x = math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * 50 + 250
    y = math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * 50 + 250
    obj = canvas.create_text(250, 250, text=text, fill="green")
    canvas.itemconfig(obj, angle=-angle)
    canvas.coords(obj, x, y)
    return obj

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)

for i in range(0,360,60):
    draw(i,"Hi")

canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```